# ViewPager Rescource not found exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm getting a resource not found exception, and I'm not exactly sure why. Am i thinking about this the wrong way? I have tried to move the setTextColor tags to different locations, but it still wont work without a exception. The only way I'm getting it to work properly is in the onCreate method. So the app is able to find the rights id's in the onCreate, but not in the other methods? Anybody have any idea why?

ViewPager adapter :

```
 package com.nordoid.tracephone;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainMenu extends FragmentActivity implements OnPageChangeListener {
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;

// MainMenu bar
 TextView home;
 TextView settings;
 TextView friends;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

    home = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mmenu_home);
    settings = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mmenu_settings);
    friends = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mmenu_friends);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mainmenu_pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    // init starting position color.
    //home.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    home.setText("HOME");
    settings.setText("SETTINGS");
    friends.setText("FRIENDS");     
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);       
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Mfragment_settings();
        case 1:
            return new Mfragment_main();
        case 2:
            return new Mfragment_friends();

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {        
}
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

      switch (arg0) {
        case 0: 
            onSettingsScreen();
            break;
        case 1:
            onHomeScreen();
            break;  
        case 2: 
            onFriendsScreen();
            break;      
        }     

}

public void onHomeScreen () {
    home.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    System.out.println("2");
    friends.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    settings.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
}

public void onSettingsScreen ()  {
    settings.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    friends.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    home.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    System.out.println("PAGE 1");
}

public void onFriendsScreen () {
    friends.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    System.out.println("3");
    home.setText(Color.GRAY);
    settings.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
}
}
```

ViewPagrAdapter layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mfrag_home" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mainmenu_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mmenu_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mmenu_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="45dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mmenu_friends"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="49dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the LogCAT error output.

```
06-23 18:50:47.685: E/InputEventReceiver(9936): Exception dispatching input event.
06-23 18:50:47.685: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936): Exception in MessageQueue callback:     handleReceiveCallback
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xff888888
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:234)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3672)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at com.nordoid.tracephone.MainMenu.onFriendsScreen(MainMenu.java:150)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at com.nordoid.tracephone.MainMenu.onPageSelected(MainMenu.java:124)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:565)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:549)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2004)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7190)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2274)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2009)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at     android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1931)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1385)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7370)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3205)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3150)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4187)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4788)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-23 18:50:47.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9936):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 18:50:47.705: W/dalvikvm(9936): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41837450)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xff888888
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:234)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3672)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at com.nordoid.tracephone.MainMenu.onFriendsScreen(MainMenu.java:150)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at com.nordoid.tracephone.MainMenu.onPageSelected(MainMenu.java:124)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:565)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:549)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2004)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7190)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2274)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2009)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1931)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1385)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7370)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3205)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3150)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4187)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4788)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-23 18:50:47.705: E/AndroidRuntime(9936):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
  home.setText(Color.GRAY); //expecting  a resource id which is an int
  // the resource does not exist. hence you get ResourceNotFoundException
```

Example:

Considering you have string resource as below

```
   <string name="app_name">MyAppName</string>
```

You can do as below

```
  home.setText(R.string.app_name);
  // the resource referred exists in string.xml.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html.

Check the doc for more infromation.

```
public final void setText (int resid)
//expects a resource id which is an integer.
```

Not sure what you are doing. If you want the Color value to be displayed you can do as below.

```
 home.setText(String.valueOf(Color.GRAY));
```